# Null pointer exception error android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

Null pointer exception error in my fragment class. I use tab activity in my program, list view is located in fragment xml file. code:

```
    package com.example.timetracker;

import ///


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener, LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1;
    private static final int RESET_STOPWATCH = 2;
    static ListView lvData;
    static DB db;
    static SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
    static Activity act;

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //create my tabs...
        }
    }


    //some code...

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            if(position == 0){  
                Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
            }

            if (position == 1)
            {
                Fragment fragment2 = new DummySectionFragment2();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment2.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 2);
                fragment2.setArguments(args);
                return fragment2;
            }
            return null;

        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment{

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        View v;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tracker,
                    container, false);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_statistic,
                    container, false);
            createList();
            return rootView;
        }

        public void createList(){
            db = new DB(act);Log.d(TAG, "1");
            db.open();Log.d(TAG, "2");

            String[] from = new String[] {DB.COLUMN_NAME, DB.COLUMN_TIME  };Log.d(TAG, "3");
            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvTextName, R.id.tvText_time};Log.d(TAG, "4");

            scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(act, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);Log.d(TAG, "5");
            lvData = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvData);Log.d(TAG, "6 ");
                    //after thap i have error
            lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);Log.d(TAG, "7");
        }
    }

    public static class DummySectionFragment2 extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>  {
            //some code....
            }


        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

    //Data base class
    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

        DB db;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DB db) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor cursor = db.getAllData();
            return cursor;
        }

    }

}
```

Don't working code "lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);Log.d(TAG, "7");" logs:

```
  04-03 20:11:54.830: D/dalvikvm(1684): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 97K, 6% free 2883K/3040K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
04-03 20:11:54.850: D/MainActivity(1684): 1
04-03 20:11:54.850: D/Data Base(1684): Открытие Подключения
04-03 20:11:54.858: D/Data Base(1684): Подключение открыто
04-03 20:11:54.858: D/MainActivity(1684): 2
04-03 20:11:54.858: D/MainActivity(1684): 3
04-03 20:11:54.858: D/MainActivity(1684): 4
04-03 20:11:54.858: D/MainActivity(1684): 6 
04-03 20:11:54.858: D/MainActivity(1684): 5
04-03 20:11:54.858: D/AndroidRuntime(1684): Shutting down VM
04-03 20:11:54.858: W/dalvikvm(1684): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c41648)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at com.example.timetracker.MainActivity$DummySectionFragment.createList(MainActivity.java:200)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at com.example.timetracker.MainActivity$DummySectionFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:187)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-03 20:11:54.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is on this line of code: `MainActivity.java:187`?

Comment: I think `act` is not initialised anywhere. Right? So, `db = new DB(act);` makes `db` null

Comment: yes, i forget to delete that var)

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `v.findViewById(R.id.lvData);` is returning null.  This would seem to be because you haven't put any views into the structure called `v`.  You are then trying to use the null on the line below, and that is what causes the exception.

Comment: if l call lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);Log.d(TAG, "6 "); (without v) i have error:"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity"

Comment: Certainly.  That's not the issue.  You have a structure with nothing in it.  You are trying to pull something out of that structure, and you're getting nothing.  You're then trying to use that nothing as if it were something.

Comment: Use a debugger to check what's in `v` when you call that line.  You'll see what I mean.